# Corda: Can an Admin see the transactions going in a Corda network?

Tags: blockchain, corda

I went through complete architecture of Corda and I understood that Corda works on need to know basis.

[image]

But, the confusion here is:

If user wants to report for dispute or some problem related with transactions, where he should go. As each user is a separate process and maintaining its own database, is there any admin which can see the complete transaction and can take some action in a dispute or a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the question.

There is no built-in concept of an administrator or centralized node as this would cause anything we build to be highly centralized (which defeats the purpose of a distributed application)

However, it is possible to include an administrator (regulator, governing body, etc.) as an additional party to all transactions within the CorDapp. This would be done explicitly, in code, by adding the administrator party (node) as a signer on all Commands or as a non-signing party to the transactions. The administrator node would receive information regarding all transactions on the network.